# G4 cert using G2 intermediary cert

Tags: openssl

I have an issue where I have an iOS app which is pinned to a root certificate of GlobalSign which is due to expire early February. This is their G2 root AlphaSSL cert.

We currently have a site certificate coming off of it which is due to expire on January 1st (10 days away) we have renewed the certificate and because its less than 6 month from the root expiry its been issued against the G4 root certificate.

If I update the site with the new cert with both the G4 issues site cert and G4 root cert the iOS app fails to work as the pinning is invalid. I have tried creating a PEM with the G4 site cert and G2 root cert but this fails for reasons I can't quite understand.

My question is am I barking up the wrong tree here is there a fundamental reason that the G4 issues site cert will not work with the G2 root cert until its expiry in Feb?

I had created the PEM as

SiteCert
RootCert
Key

Comment: You need to be way more specific here so that we can answer your question. Please describe what the new trust path will be exactly and which part of this trust chain is in the trust store of your application and at which parts of your chain your application pins.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich I have update the question to clearify its pinning to the signature of the root cert. We can't switch to the G4 root cert as without update the apps wont be able to access the server and I am seeing errors when trying to use the G4 site cert with the G2 root cert. Worth also saying the G2 root cert expires itself in Feb.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @Community now cleared up to hopefully get to the point better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...  the G4 issues site cert will not work with the G2 root cert

Neither G2 nor G4 are root certificates, these are intermediate certificates issued by the GlobalSign Root CA.

> .. fails to work as the pinning is invalid

A certificate is either issued by G2 or G4, not both. So if your new certificate is issued by G4 then the existing pinning to G2 will fail.

The validation against the trust root GlobalSign Root CA is not affected by the change of intermediate CA.

Comment: Thank you. I have clarified and the pinning is against the intermediary cert not the root cert as you have explained above. 

Thank you for your help.